# Mysql - simplify query EXIST with null

Tags: mysql, exists

Can i simplify this part of query ?

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT a_response from answer where a_userID = ? AND a_questionID = q_id)
            THEN (SELECT a_response from answer where a_userID = ? AND a_questionID = q_id) ELSE null END
```

or complete query :

```
SELECT q_id, q_question, q_userID, q_targetID, concat(u_firstname, ' ',u_lastname), 
        CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT a_response from answer where a_userID = ? AND a_questionID = q_id)
            THEN (SELECT a_response from answer where a_userID = ? AND a_questionID = q_id) ELSE null END,
        (SELECT count(a_id) FROM answer WHERE a_questionID = q_id),
        (SELECT count(a_id) FROM answer WHERE a_questionID = q_id AND a_response = 1)
    FROM question INNER JOIN user ON q_userID = u_id
    where q_targetID = ?
    ORDER BY q_created DESC LIMIT ?, 10
```

Comment: It would be best to get rid of the subqueries in select and join to them instead - you can "create" a derived table (by specifying the subquery in the FROM/JOIN clause instead) and join to it - that way the CASE maps to a LEFT JOIN and the two counts can be computed using one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `exists` in the first place.  The subquery will just work.  If there are no rows, a scalar subquery returns `NULL`:

```
SELECT q_id, q_question, q_userID, q_targetID,
       concat(u_firstname, ' ', u_lastname), 
       (SELECT a_response FROM answer WHERE a_userID = ? AND a_questionID = q_id),
       (SELECT count(a_id) FROM answer WHERE a_questionID = q_id),
       (SELECT count(a_id) FROM answer WHERE a_questionID = q_id AND a_response = 1)
FROM question INNER JOIN
     user
     ON q_userID = u_id
WHERE q_targetID = ?
ORDER BY q_created DESC
LIMIT ?, 10;
```